# Asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynccallback

I've written a function which makes an asynchronous request using jQuery.

```
var Site = {

    asyncRequest : function(url, containerId) {        
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            onSuccess: function(data){
                $(containerId).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Syntax might be slightly wrong as I'm using notepad, but hopefully you get the idea.

I call the function:

```
Site.asyncRequest('someurl', container1);
Site.asyncRequest('someurl', container2);
```

Both requests get sent and processed by the server. Two responses get sent back, which is what I expect. However, I would expect container1 and container2 to contain responses from both requests.

The problem, is that only the last response gets displayed and I can't figure out why. I don't know how the jQuery ajax keeps a track of requests/responses, so maybe this is a problem.

Say I make 5 or 10 requests, how does jQuery ajax know which response is for which request and where does it keep a track of it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, thank you. I could try passing a function as a parameter and then call that function from OnSuccess. I'll see if I can get that to work. My main concern is that I can't easily debug and track what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a Javascript scoping issue. Try the following:

```
var Site = {
    asyncRequest: function(url, containerId) {
        (function(theContainer) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                onSuccess: function(data) {
                    $(theContainer).html(data);
                }
            });
        })(containerId);
    }
};
```

This creates a separate scope for each function call, so the actual value pointed to by "theContainer" is different for each onSuccess anonymous function.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, that's not the case, actually, for a somewhat obscure reason: The ``.ajax`` method is using the ``url`` parameter within the current event of the event loop while the ``containerId``/``theContainer`` value is being used in another event later on in the event loop. Since Javascript is a single thread, it's impossible for the ``url`` parameter to be anything other than what we intended it to be. We'd only have to re-scope the ``url`` if the ``onSuccess`` function needed to make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is a single closure is getting created, due to the way that function is declared.  See "A more advanced example" here:  http://skilldrick.co.uk/2010/11/a-brief-introduction-to-closures/

Basically, the `containerId` is being shared among all instances of that `onSuccess` anonymous function.  I haven't tested this, but I believe if you defined your `asyncRequest` function outside of `Site`, this would work.

As far as a more elegant solution to this problem, perhaps someone else will answer better.